# How to show the last commit date in a web page in Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

We want to show the date a prototype was last updated, on a web page.

We've tried using a [git log parser](https://github.com/domharrington/node-gitlog) but it seems like Heroku strips the .git directory, so it doesn't work.

Any idea on how to include the .git directory, or achieve this in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm recording an alternate answer we've received from elsewhere as it's been very useful.

This solution is to use Git hooks to set a Heroku config variable, which can then be read by the app.

If you add this to `.git/hooks/pre-push`:

```
date=$(git log -1 --format="%cd")
heroku config:set UPDATED_DATE="$date" --app your-app-name
```

then every push will update the UPDATED_DATE environment variable on Heroku

you can [format the date differently](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) as needed

In Node you can access this variable with this:

```
process.env.UPDATED_DATE
```

Answer (score 6):

You could query the Heroku Platform API to find out when the latest release was and return that on your web page. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#release-list for more information; you'll probably want the `created_at` attribute of `release`.